# Is it possible to go through all the if statements in the function?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def ShortestDistance(maps,i,j,short,k): #i,j-->current position.
    x=0
    y=0
    for a in range(0, len(maps)):
        for b in range(0, len(maps[0])):
            if maps[a][b] == 2:
                x = a
                y = b

    if (i==x) and (j==y):
        short=min(short,k)
        return short

    maps[i][j]=3

    if within(i+1,j) and possible(maps,i+1,j):
        return ShortestDistance(maps,i+1,j,short,k+1)

    if within(i, j+1) and possible(maps,i, j+1):
        return ShortestDistance(maps,i,j+1,short,k+1)

    if within(i-1,j) and possible(maps,i-1,j):
        return ShortestDistance(maps,i-1,j,short,k+1)

    if within(i,j-1) and possible(maps,i,j-1):
        return ShortestDistance(maps,i,j-1,short,k+1)

    maps[i][j]=0

result=ShortestDistance(maps,0,0,longest,0)
if result is None:
    answer=-1
else:
    answer=result
```

What I'm trying to do here is to have the function go through all the if statements in the function whether the previous if statement was true or not.
For instance, I want my 3rd if statement in my code to go through as well even if the 2nd one was true (in this case, it seems like the computer isn't going through the 3rd one).
My ultimate goal is to find the minimum value of k for ALL THE POSSIBLE CASES.
How would I be able to make it possible?

Comment: You've got `return` statements within the `if` conditionals. If you want to go through all the `if` statements, move the `return` statement to the end and store whatever you want in variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with `return` statements. Once the function encounters one it exits.
Try something like this instead:

```
def ShortestDistance(maps,i,j,short,k):
    #...
    distances = []
    if within(i+1,j) and possible(maps,i+1,j):
        distances.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i+1,j,short,k+1))

    if within(i, j+1) and possible(maps,i, j+1):
        distances.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i,j+1,short,k+1))

    if within(i-1,j) and possible(maps,i-1,j):
        distances.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i-1,j,short,k+1))

    if within(i,j-1) and possible(maps,i,j-1):
        distances.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i,j-1,short,k+1))

    return min(distances)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
def ShortestDistance(maps,i,j,short,k): #i,j-->current position.
    x=0
    y=0
    for a in range(0, len(maps)):
        for b in range(0, len(maps[0])):
            if maps[a][b] == 2:
                x = a
                y = b

    if (i==x) and (j==y):
        short=min(short,k)
        return short

    maps[i][j]=3
    resx = []
    if within(i+1,j) and possible(maps,i+1,j):
        resx.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i+1,j,short,k+1))

    if within(i, j+1) and possible(maps,i, j+1):
        resx.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i,j+1,short,k+1))

    if within(i-1,j) and possible(maps,i-1,j):
        resx.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i-1,j,short,k+1))

    if within(i,j-1) and possible(maps,i,j-1):
        resx.append(ShortestDistance(maps,i,j-1,short,k+1))

    maps[i][j]=0
    return min(resx)

result=ShortestDistance(maps,0,0,longest,0)
if result is None:
    answer=-1
else:
    answer=result
```